# java method not applicable to the arguments (interfaces)

Tags: java

I am fairly new to java and haven't used interfaces much, and this is what I imagine is a very basic question.

I define an interface, a second interface that extends it, and then a class which implements the second interface:

```
public interface I1 {
  public void doStuff();
}

public interface I2 extends I1 {
  public void doMoreStuff();
}

public class C2 implements I2 {
  public void doStuff(){
    // implements I1 as required
  }
  public void doMoreStuff(){
    // implements I1 as required
  }
}
```

I then want to invoke a method that has as an argument a collection of objects which implement the interface I1:

```
public class C3 {
   public static void doI1Stuff(List<I1> implementorsOfI1){
      // code here
   }
}
```

but I get the abovementioned error when I try something like

```
C2 aC2 = new C2();
List c2L = new List<I2>();
c2L.add(aC2);
C3.doI1Stuff(c2L);
```

What I've done seems reasonable to me as a java novice.  Why doesn't it work, and what would a more experienced programmer do?   I hope I've made very simple mistake somewhere and this is actually possible...

(revised question: it works (as replies stated) if I am dealing with a single C2 object, but not with a collection of them...)

Comment: This should work fine. What's the exact compiler error you are getting? Make sure you're not doing something odd like importing a different class with the same name - that's often an issue when you're experimenting.

Comment: Your example looks fine to me.

Comment: Do you have any code where you've written `// code here` in the body of `doI1Stuff(...)`?

Comment: I have just compiled it and it works fine, so not only is it possible - this one is working. I coppied exactly your code. Maybe you should search for some misspelling.

Comment: Is that message an error, or just a warning? Are you using an IDE or just compiling/running from the command line? Are you using an old version of Java? The good news is your code is correct.

Comment: Can't instantiate `List`; if that's changed to an implementation (such as `ArrayList`) it gives the warning "C3.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations," but still compiles and runs as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Ooops, your c2L is a `List`, not a List`. This should compile -- and it does for as it does for others who commented -- though it is dangerous for same reason I describe below. I will leave this answer here for now, but I can delete it if I find it is not useful

---

```
 public static void doI1Stuff(List<I1> implementorsOfI1)
 ...
 C3.doI1Stuff(c2L);
```

`doI1Stuff` expects a `List<I1>` but you are passing it a `List<I2>` which is not allowed. As strange as it sounds, "A bag of Apples is not a a bag of Fruit". The reason being that you can put *any* fruit in a Bag of Fruit, e.g. Banana but you can't do that with a Bag of Apple.

To relate it your example consider there is also a `class C1 extends I1`. `doI1Stuff` can add a `C3` the paramer, breaking the contract. It might clarify to realize that your parameter is named wrong, it should be `listOfImplementorsOfT1`.

One way to fix your problem is to change the declaration to

```
 public static void doI1Stuff(List<? extends I1> implementorsOfI1)
```

This says the parameter is a list of *some unknown type* that `extends I1`. `List<I2>`, `List<C2>`, `List<C1>` all meet satisfy constraint. With this declaration, the method cannot add anything to that list, because it doesn't know what that type is.

Comment: I think I understand.  The danger is that doI1Stuff might try to add some non-I2-compliant object to the collection that was passed to it, so upon returning to the caller potentially bad things could happen.

Comment: You got it :) But see my update, your example as is compiles after some necessary changes. Perhaps you can post the code verbatim?